# Best way to check when an element is not undefined

Tags: javascript

While I'm observing a web-page there is a button that after I click an element appears.
I already have the `id` of that element, what I want to do in a single code:
press the button, wait for the specific element to appear (become defined), perform an action.
What I tried to do is this:

```
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.click();
while(document.getElementById("id") == undefined){
     continue;
}
console.log("element is loaded!!");
```

That code didn't work for me (the browser got stuck).
I thought also to pause the code for specific time that it gets to the element to appear (sleep), but is there a better way?
Again, I don't have access to the code of the web-page, so I can't rais a flag when this element is loaded.

Comment: Use a mutation observer. I assume you know when this element will appear in the document. Once the click occurs, set the observer to observe. And this will work. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Bibberty the observ() function takes target and options as parameters, I see the target is the element that I want to observe, but I can't figure what the options should be

Comment: No, just observe the area where is will be added (or the whole document). When a DOM event occurs you will get a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Promise:

```js
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.click();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  while (document.getElementById("id") == undefined) {}
  resolve();
}).then(() => {
  console.log("element is loaded!!");
});
```

Comment: Thats simillar to what I did and it doesn't work, browser freezes

Answer (score 0):

globally, if you want to check if the variable is set :

```
if(variable)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set an interval

```
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.click();
let intv = setInterval(() => {
  if (!!document.getElementById("id")) {
  console.log('the element is here');
  clearInterval(this);
  }}, 200);
}
console.log("element is loaded!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check whether the element exists everytime a change in the DOM occurs:

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(() => document.getElementById('id') ? console.log("loaded") : '');

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true
});
```

Demo:

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(() => document.getElementById('id') ? console.log("loaded") : '');

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true
});

/* below is simply for demonstration */

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("p"), {id: 'id',innerHTML: 'Hello World!'}));
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click to add an element in 1 second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably crashing because the code is executed too many times in the while loop.

You could try using `MutationObserver` to listen for change in DOM.

Or

Add use `setInterval` instead of the while loop.

```js
let interval;

function handleClick() {
  // add the new element after 5 seconds
  const divNode = document.createElement('div');
  divNode.id = 'newElement';

  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.append(divNode);
  }, 5000);
  
  // every second check for the element
  interval = window.setInterval(() => {
    checkIfElementIsInDom();
  }, 1000);
}

function checkIfElementIsInDom() {
  console.log('Checking...');
  const newNode = document.getElementById('newElement');
  if (newNode) {
    console.log('completed!');
    // stop the interval
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

const buttonNode = document.getElementById('button');
buttonNode.addEventListener('click', handleClick.bind(this));
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector('.test');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
            // Check for our new item
            const itm = document.querySelector('.itm');
            if (itm) {
              console.log('we found our item');
              observer.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Add an item.
    document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML = '<div class="itm">Here it is</div>';
  }, 5000);
  
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="test">

</section>
```